# What are the standards for security on the web and web development?

Tags: security, standards

What are the standards that govern security practices on the web and web development?  What standards body publishes such documents?

Comment: The industry standard seem to be to just botch it. If someone is interested enough to look and finds a vulnerability, try to weasel out of it.

Comment: @Tom Hawtin And thats exactly why security researches go full disclosure on BugTraq and then everyone gets hacked because there isn't a patch.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the industry.  Credit Cards use the [PCI-DSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard).  The US medial industry uses [HIPAA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Health_Insurance_Portability_and_Accountability_Act).  Cryptographic systems are governed by [FIPS-140](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140) which was created by NIST.  Then there is the [CWE](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/slices/2000.html) system which is a list of every known vulnerability type.

Comment: I believe that is HIPAA, but your link is solid.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page).

> The Open Web Application Security
>   Project (OWASP) is a 501c3
>   not-for-profit worldwide charitable
>   organization focused on improving the
>   security of application software.

Comment: OWASP does not publish technology standards.

Answer (score 1):

Most general and apply to any developpement but interesting anyway :

[CWE/SANS TOP 25 Most Dangerous Programming Errors](http://www.sans.org/top25-programming-errors/?utm_source=web&utm_medium=text-ad&utm_content=Announcement_Bar_20090111&utm_campaign=Top25&ref=37029)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standards governing security practices specifically focussed on web apps, but the ISO27000 family of standards cover information systems in general. Warning: getting hold of a copy of ISO2700x, unless you work for ISO or a university, is not cheap...